How can I tell when it's safe to set TreeView.SelectedItem?
Here's a really simple bit of xaml:
    <TreeView x:Name="provenanceTree" 
                  ItemsSource="{x:Bind ProvenanceTreeItems}" SelectionMode="Single"
                  SelectedItem="{x:Bind focus, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  >
        <!-- Definitions in here -->
    </TreeView>

The idea here is that there's a focus for the control, and the treeview's selection should follow that focus.
Mostly, it works.  But the problem comes about when a change of focus requires additions to the ItemsSource - that is: I'm trying to both add an item and select it in the same operation.  Naturally, the TreeView redraws, but nothing gets selected - if anything was selected previously it gets de-selected.
I tried assigning the SelectedItem not in a bindng, but in the refocussing code, but I hit the same problem.
I get it: changes to the ItemsSource don't get passed to the TreeView right away, so I'm trying to select something that's not in the tree.   How can I tell when it is safe to select a newly-added item?  And is there any way to adust the binding so it works as intended?

You just need to add the new item and pass it as the SelectedItem. For example, the following code works (the new item is selected):
private void AddingTestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var newItem = new ProvenanceTreeItems();
    ProvenanceTreeItems.Add(newItem);
    // Assuming that the TreeView's x:Name is "TreeViewControl".
    TreeViewControl.SelectedItem = newItem;
}


That's exactly what I had before I tried to bind it.  That didn't work either.
I wonder if I've misdiagnosed?  Does an item need to be expanded and visible before it can be selected?

The item doesn't need to be visible to be selected. The sample code works in my answer works. My first guess is that the item you are setting as SelectedItem, doesn't match the Type of items of the TreeView. Might be better if you fix your other question first.

I think I might have found it.  The item doesn't need to be visible, but it does need to be realised - That means, if it's visible and on-screen, then it's definitely realised, and if it's in the collection but not yet shown (e.g. because the parent is collapsed) then it's not realised, and otherwise it may or may not be realised dependeing on how the control handles its memory. I Found a code sample for MS that shows how to expand and scroll into view each node progressively (but I've lost it again - I'll update here if I find it)
